# Jmeter Dashboard Fails with Pipe Delimiter jtl

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-3.2

I am launching jemeter test from the command line with an override for the output log file set to a pipe "|"  with:

`jmeter.save.saveservice.default_delimiter='|'`

This is working without issue and logs using the default 16 columns for jmeter 3.2 to a file name "run_results.jtl"

The issue I am having is now that I swapped the delimiter from a comma I cannot jun the dashboard.  I get an error saying either:

- the column counts do not match 185 expected and only found 16 check your jmeter.save.saveservice.* settings
- Cannot find column name timeStamp (Yet it is the first column)

I have looked in both user and jmeter property files and neither have anything un-commented for these fields and the dashboard will create without issue for a csv with a comma delimiter (I tried replacing all | with , and it works). This applies for any test data I have thrown at it.  I was using a simple api call to post one call and captured the default logs with the "-l" flag.

The dashboard is run with the trailing command:

`-e -o c:\test\dashboard`

What else can I try or look at here?

Jmeter - 3.2
Java 8
Windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.04 same results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your issue:

[image: JMeter Generate Dashboard Custom Delimiter]

So a couple of recommendations:

1. In order to be able to generate dashboard you need to have **the same** [Results File Configuration](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config), inconsistencies might have negative impact on dashboard creation process, especially the delimiter. Given configuration match during .jtl results file and dashboard generation - there should be no issues.
2. As per [JMeter Best Practices](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#best_practices) it is [strongly recommended to always use the latest JMeter version](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version) so try upgrading to [JMeter 4.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-in-jmeter-4)
3. In case if you are not in position to upgrade to JMeter 4.0 perform clean installation of JMeter 3.2 (you can find it under [JMeter Archives](https://archive.apache.org/dist/jmeter/binaries/)) and try running the below commands for pipe and comma delimiters:

   - pipe: `jmeter -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.default_delimiter="|" -n -t test.jmx -l pipe.jtl -e -o pipe`
   - comma: `jmeter -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.default_delimiter=, -n -t test.jmx -l comma.jtl -e -o comma`

Comment: I tried to re-download 3.2 and it was without change.  I downloaded 4.0 and it works without issue.  I am surprised this was not found anywhere as a bug honestly, I couldnt find anyone else online with this issue.  I cannot be the only one who had issues with failure messages containing commas and breaking the comma based csv.  Thanks @Dmitri T